# How many tanks does an A350 have?

Tags: fuel-tanks, airbus-a350

How many tanks are there on an A350? Where are they located? Is it a common configuration among large aircraft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two configurations of [A350](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A350_XWB#Specifications) have different capacity.

- A350-900: 138,000 liters / 36,456 US gallons
- A350-1000: 156,000 liters / 41,212 US gallons

The tanks are shown in this picture:

[image: wing tanks]
<sup>*[Source](http://bloga350.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-much-fuel-can-a350-hold.html)*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **Farhan**'s answer, we can also say that A350-900ULR (Ultra Long Range) version, capable of [20 hours of non-stop flights and up to 9,700 nautical miles](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/news/en/2018/09/ultra-long-range-a350-xwb-goes-the-distance.html), or [1,600 more than the standard A350-900](https://www.ausbt.com.au/the-secret-to-airbus-ultra-long-range-a350-jets-there-isn-t-one), integrates a modified fuel system, which increases the aircraft’s fuel carrying capacity by 24,000 litres without the need for additional fuel tanks, [increasing fuel carrying capacity from 141,000 litres to 165,000 litres](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2015/10/airbus-launches-new-ultra-long-range-version-of-the-a350-900.html).

Benefitting from the A350-900’s unique flexibility, [the extended range capability does not involve installation of additional fuel tanks](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/a350xwb-family/a350-900.html), but rather an adaptation of the fuel system within the existing fuel tank.

Comment: So the standard A350-900 has large unusable spaces in its fuel tanks?

Comment: Yes, in a some way, it uses additional space already available in the existing tanks and some of the engineering development, involved the relocation of sensors in the fuel system, enabling existing tanks to carry the maximum fuel load for the ULR. In addition, there are some minor aerodinamic improvements and an increased MTOW.